# git config does not set vimdiff layout properly

Tags: vimdiff, git

I'm trying to configure vimdiff as a git merge tool, so my global git config contains the following lines:

```
[merge]
    tool = vimdiff
    conflictstyle = diff3
    prompt = true
[mergetool "vimdiff"]
    layout = "LOCAL,MERGED,REMOTE"
```

I want to get a specific layout, and not the default one, so I define the `layout` variable as indicated here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool#_vimdiff. However, when running `git mergetool`, vimdiff totally ignores these settings and fires its default 4-window layout.

What is wrong with that config? How could I setup a non-default layout in this case?

git version 2.25.1,
vim version 9.0

Comment: IIRC, the layout functionality was only added in `git` version `2.37` (this is also indicated by switching to the previous version of the online manpage in the link you provided).
Thus it's probably not available in your version. An easy check would be to run `man git-mergetool` on your machine and verify that the `layout` section is missing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which seems to be _the_ answer: `man git-mergetool` does not contain `layout` for my version of git, gonna update it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was added in `git` version `2.37`.
Quoting from [the changelog](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqy1xinf00.fsf@gitster.g/T/#u):

> - "vimdiff[123]" mergetool drivers have been reimplemented with a
>   more generic layout mechanism.

This means that in order to use the new layout mechanism, you need to upgrade your git installation to this (or a newer) version.